# Suppress scientific notation in pandas read_sql

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When reading a database table data in to pandas dataframe `0.00` is loading as `0E-2` how can we suppress this scientific notation? Can any one help me

Answer (score 1):

Just change the data type of the required column to numeric:

```
import pandas as pd
df.colname = pd.to_numeric(df.colname)
```